# ocamlbuild produces a blank archive file rather than an executable

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild

Working on a Debian-based Linux distro (PopOS), I have a folder of files and a Makefile containing

```
MODULES=move score main draw setup
OBJECTS=$(MODULES:=.cmo)
TEST=test.byte
OCAMLBUILD=ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind
MAIN=main.byte

# Recipes 
default: build #first build (dependies) then run utop (command)
    utop

build: 
    $(OCAMLBUILD) $(OBJECTS) 

test:
    $(OCAMLBUILD) -tag 'debug' $(TEST) && ./$(TEST)

play:
    $(OCAMLBUILD) $(MAIN) && ./$(MAIN)

clean:
    ocamlbuild -clean
```

When I call `make build` it seems to work just fine, but the resulting `.byte` files don't run.  In the terminal they show up in red, which indicates that the computer is understanding them to be archive files rather than executables.  When I try to run `./main.byte` it says the file cannot be found even though the file is listed in the directory.

Moreover, when I build this on a Mac it works just fine.  It builds the program and runs it correctly.

Any thoughts about what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure why this works on a Mac but not my Linux machine, but I did manage to play with this enough to get a solution.  If I change the Makefile to be

```
MODULES=move score main draw setup
OBJECTS=$(MODULES:=.cmo)
TEST=test.byte
OCAMLBUILD=ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind
MAIN=main.byte


default: build 
    utop

build: 
    $(OCAMLBUILD) $(OBJECTS) $(MAIN)

test:
    $(OCAMLBUILD) -tag 'debug' $(TEST) && ./$(TEST)

play:
    $(OCAMLBUILD) $(MAIN) && ./$(MAIN)

clean:
    ocamlbuild -clean
```

then the computer recognizes the executable.

Answer (score 0):

In your original Makefile, `make build` does not run the command `ocamlbuild $(MAIN)` which should create the bytecode executable. You have to run `make play` for the bytecode executable to be built. In the modified Makefile, you included `$(MAIN)` in the list of targets passed to ocamlbuild in your `build` Makefile target, so now it is built by `make build`.